# Time of Android phone on first boot after unboxing?

Tags: android, android-source

What will be the display time and date on first boot after unboxing android device if it is not connected to internet connection or without sim? On what basis the time and date is setup by default?

Answer (score 1):

On the first boot, android will set the system time with Build.TIME. And   Build.TIME is get from system prop ro.build.data.rtc, which is the time when the image is build. Some factory test will be executed in factory, so it will have been boot some times. It may not be the first boot when user unbox the phone, and boot it.

This is done by AlarmManagerService.java#[onStart](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/alarm/AlarmManagerService.java;drc=e83313260139f68cc78d82a1d23a3af75a011df2;l=1611).

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mInjector.init();
        ...

        synchronized (mLock) {
            mHandler = new AlarmHandler();
            mConstants = new Constants();
            ...

            // We have to set current TimeZone info to kernel
            // because kernel doesn't keep this after reboot
            setTimeZoneImpl(SystemProperties.get(TIMEZONE_PROPERTY));

            // Ensure that we're booting with a halfway sensible current time.  Use the
            // most recent of Build.TIME, the root file system's timestamp, and the
            // value of the ro.build.date.utc system property (which is in seconds).
            final long systemBuildTime = Long.max(
                    1000L * SystemProperties.getLong("ro.build.date.utc", -1L),
                    Long.max(Environment.getRootDirectory().lastModified(), Build.TIME));
            if (mInjector.getCurrentTimeMillis() < systemBuildTime) {
                Slog.i(TAG, "Current time only " + mInjector.getCurrentTimeMillis()
                        + ", advancing to build time " + systemBuildTime);
                mInjector.setKernelTime(systemBuildTime);
            }
```

Comment: Yong, Thank you so much